# alternator overcharging

Tags: alternator

I had a bad TPS on my 2009 Montana. I replaced it with a used scrap-yard TPS and the car runs great now. However, now my dashboard meter reads 15v. It's the uper limit, but it used to be 14.2v ish before. Is it a problem? It was -20 degrees outside and the car was running&starting so badly that I, of course, drained the battery alot trying to start&ride with the defective TPS. I cleaned the battery terminals and there doesn't seem to be any other obvious electrical wire damaged. The battery is 1 year old.

Comment: Now that you have freshly cleaned terminals, the alternator is busy giving the battery the full charge it was lacking. The volt reading should come back to normal. If you like, you can use a battery charger to bring the battery up. Disconnect the battery from the vehicle wiring first.

Comment: Thank's,I think you're right. I drove 2 hours yesterday and the voltage is now at about 14.5v. Close enough to almost normal in -20 C... :)